# Could not find or load main class TestHBase

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I'm trying to compile and run my simple test HBase code in java using terminal Ubuntu 14.04, I've install Hadoop and HBase correctlly and are running. 
The code is :

```
/*
 * Compile and run with:
 * javac -cp `hbase classpath` TestHBase.java 
 * java -cp `hbase classpath` TestHBase
 */
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.*;

public class TestHBase {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf);
        try {
            HTable table = new HTable(conf, "test-table");
            Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("test-key"));
            put.add(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("q"), Bytes.toBytes("value"));
            table.put(put);
        } finally {
            admin.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I've got the long string 'hbase classpath' and the command

```
javac -cp 'hbase classpath' TestHBase.java
```

run correctly giving TestHBase.class file, but when I run the command

```
java -cp 'hbase classpath' TestHBase
```

it gives this error :

```
Error: Could not find or load main class
```

How could I solve this ?

Here is my terminal screenshot
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M46mJ.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lImbY.png)

Comment: Can you please give the full path to your TestHBase. I think the .class is in a different folder something like java -cp 'hbase classpath' c:\temp\TestHBase

Comment: my TestHBase.java file is in /home (i'm using ubuntu) , and after command `javac -cp 'hbase classpath' TestHBase.java` I see TestHBase.class creating in /home, but when I issue command `java -cp 'hbase classpath' TestHBase`, it gives error. In addition I try a simple "hello world" java code using terminal and it works correctly.

Comment: Can you please post a screen shot of your command prompt

Comment: Yes, for sure. I added two screenshot in the end of the main post. The first is when I issue `javac -cp 'hbase classpath' TestHBase.java` and the second is when I issue `java -cp 'hbase classpath' TestHBase`. you can see TestHBase.java file in /home directory. Thanks

Comment: i had a look at your screenshot but not sure what is amiss. Hopefully the below link provides you some answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean